# Best primitive type for fast number comparison?

Tags: java, numbers, comparison

I've got a function that does several hundred million iterations, trying to find the optimal combination of a given set of possibilities. All of my data is pre-calculated and nearly all the arithmetic is simple `>=` or `<=` comparison of these pre-calculated values.

I'm wondering if there's an advantage to using certain primitive types (`int`, `long`, `double`) when doing this simple comparison.

I know I could go and run a test to see which is "best" but it's also important to understand the underlying reasoning. For example, maybe `int` is most easily comparable because it takes up less memory, or maybe `double`'s floating point more easily tells what power of 10 the value is which speeds up comparison in some cases. I'm interested to know these basics and a simple test wouldn't tell me that.

Comment: Depends on your use-case and whether or not you want to deal with overflow.

Comment: first do what is right then measure and then change anything if at all needed.

Comment: @JacobG. what do you mean overflow? Like surpassing Integer.MAX_VALUE? Everything is pre-calculated, so I could suppress overflow by reducing the values to a desired power of 10 to avoid overflow altogether.

Comment: ["*Premature optimization is the root of all evil.**" -- Donald Ervin Knuth](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: It depends on your JVM, operating system, CPU. As you already assumed, yes, go and test on your particular environment.

Comment: @Turing85 thanks for -1 I'm assuming. Optimization isn't always premature, as is the case here.

Comment: @KaelEppcohen Your assumption is wrong. If you have determined that you have a performance problem, please share the relevant code, as well as the (essential) performance data instead of presenting a partial solution to avoid the [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2):

This is premature optimization. You should pick one data type, make an implementation based on it, and run a performance benchmark using your actual implementation, not some made-up test that compares tens of thousands random values of a specific type.

The reason to test using your specific implementation is that there is a number of factors that have a much greater effect on the speed than the timing of raw comparisons:

- **Cache hit ratio** - accessing memory is multiple times slower than accessing a cached value. Re-structuring your loops when accessing large arrays of data could speed up your program by a large factor without changing the number of raw comparisons that your program performs
- **Branch predictions** - keeping CPU pipeline going is very important. If your loops and your data are structured in a way that optimizes the number of correct branch predictions, your code runs a lot faster than code with large number of incorrect branch predictions

It is not possible to measure any of these metrics until you have your actual algorithm implemented. Once you optimized the actual implementation for cache and branching, switching the underlying data type becomes a relatively easy task.